# iOS error: [FBAccessTokenData userID]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, facebook, parse-platform

I am trying to build and run an old project I was working on (and had to update the SDK's for Parse and Facebook) and when I try to login to facebook with the block:

```
[PFFacebookUtils logInWithPermissions:permissionsArray block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
    //[_activityIndicator stopAnimating]; // Hide loading indicator

    if (!user) {
        if (!error) {
            NSLog(@"Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Uh oh. An error occurred: %@", error);
        }
    } else if (user.isNew) {
        NSLog(@"User with facebook signed up and logged in!");
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"LoginToProfile" sender:self];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"User with facebook logged in!");
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"LoginToProfile" sender:self];
    }
}];
```

the block simply exits and I get an error in the console:

```
[FBAccessTokenData userID]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15d88710
```

I don't know how to step into the facebook framework to debug (it just goes to assembly code). What could be the issue?

(I'm using Xcode 6.2 and iOS 8.2)

Also, how do I check the version of the Facebook and Parse SDK's I have? Where is this info located?

Answer (score 0):

Parse.framework contains info.plist file. The key "Bundle version" corresponds to parse sdk version that you're using.

As of version 3. facebook SDK declares macros 
    FB_IOS_SDK_VERSION_STRING
which indicates the version of facebook sdk that you are using.

As for the issue, you will probably need to move to facebook sdk v4.
you can find it here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/downloads
And you will need another parse framework which called PFFacebookUtilsV4. It can be downloaded from parse's official website

Alternatively you can try check this thread
https://www.parse.com/questions/is-pfloginview-updated-for-new-parsefacebook-integration

Comment: So I switched over to FB sdk v4, and then deleted my ParseFacebookUtils framework and added in the ParseFacebookUtilsV4 framework. In the class where im trying to login, i have 
`#import <ParseFacebookUtilsV4/PFFacebookUtils.h>`
but Im getting an error on loginWithPermissions saying 
`No known class method for selector 'logInWithPermissions:block:'`

Comment: Also now with the new ParseFacebookUtilsV4, im getting errors that it cant find things like "FBRequest" and "FBAppCall".

Comment: Unfortunatelly ParseFacebookUtilsV4 introduces new interface for facebook managment and it hasn't been inroduced in parse docs yet. You will have to dive into [migration quide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/upgrading-4.x) to migrate the code.

Another quick solution is to download facebookSDK package 3.23.2, plug it into the project and switch back to ParseFacebookUtils. That should fix the original problem with `[FBAccessTokenData userID]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15d88710`